# Collision detection on table

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I build on solidwork a simple model of table, then I convert it onto dae to insert into gazebo.
I want to known if I can add this dae file directly on gazebo or should I add my table piece by piece to be able to make my robot going through without strange colision?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377658/collision-detection-on-table/) by [arno](https://answers.ros.org/users/73570/arno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can [certainly use a .dae file as a collision model in Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=import_mesh). A very simple `model.sdf` file for a *static* table could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <model name="my_mesh">
    <pose>0 0 0  0 0 0</pose>
    <static>true</static>
    <link name="body">
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <mesh><uri>file://my_mesh.dae</uri></mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <mesh><uri>file://my_mesh.dae</uri></mesh>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

You can also model your table piece by piece if you really want, but I see no point in doing so. If you want your table to move when your robot bumps into it, you can set the `static` tag to `false` and add an [inertial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=inertia&cat=build_robot) block using solidworks values or otherwise generated values.

I will also make you aware of the [Solidworks to URDF exporter](http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter), which can be handy for more advanced models (though I wouldn't bother for simple rigid models like a table).

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1